# Exchange parameters

Tags: prolog

I have the following facts:

```
    make(product_A, product_Z, product_Y).
    make(P, X, Y) :- make(P, Y, X).
```

I'd like to make sure that semi-products (i.e. product_Z and product_Y) from which product_A is being made will be true regardless their position as put in a query.

So I wanted that this query:

```
make(product_A, product_Y, product_Z).
```

and this one:

```
make(product_A, product_Z, product_Y).
```

should be treated by Prolog as equivalents (the same) - even if I didn't placed both cases as facts into Prolog's data base. In other words I'd like to have parameters (product_Z and product_Y) to be exchangable in a query.

But when I put the code as at the beginning, Prolog seems to repeat an infinite loop.

So how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason for the infinite derivation is that it is possible to flip the arguments back (and forth, as long as you like). You can introduce a new name for the flipping predicate:

```
cmake(A,B,C) :- make(A,B,C).
cmake(A,B,C) :- make(A,C,B).
```

In contrast to the solution with once, you stay logically pure.

Even though flipping arguments works, for more than two dependencies, you exponentially blow up the search space (since you need to cover all permutations of n arguments). As an alternative, you could pass a sorted list of dependencies as second argument. Then you sort your input once and do the lookup.

Comment: Thanks. So a list needs to be sorted because of ensuring the parameters order, and I should then create all facts in alphabetical order as well?

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `once` to your rule, like so:

`make(A, B, C) :- once(make(A, C, B)).`

This way, it stops processing facts and will not be on an infinite loop.